# Send file lines over RFComm with pyBluez: unexpected result

Tags: python-2.7, rfcomm

Running python 2.7

Read the file and send:

```
with open(payload) as f:
        for line in f:
            syslog.syslog("Send script line: " + data)
            sock.send(line)
```

Receive:

```
while True:
    data = self._client_sock.recv(1024)
    syslog.syslog("Script line: " + data)
```

What i send:

```
raspiducky.py: Send script line: GUI d
raspiducky.py: Send script line: DELAY 50
raspiducky.py: Send script line: WINDOWS
raspiducky.py: Send script line: DELAY 50
raspiducky.py: Send script line: STRING terminal
raspiducky.py: Send script line: ENTER
raspiducky.py: Send script line: DELAY 2000
```

What i receive:

```
raspiducky.py: Script line: GUI d
raspiducky.py: Script line: DELAY 50#012WINDOWS#012DELAY 50#012STRING terminal#012ENTER#012DELAY 2000
```

Only the first line is received as expected.
What i'm doing wrong with the rest of the lines?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Send:

```
with open(payload) as f:
        for line in f:
            sock.send(struct.pack('!I', len(line)))
            sock.send(line)
```

Receive:

```
while True:
      lengthbuf = self._client_sock.recv(4)
      length, = struct.unpack('!I', lengthbuf)
      data = self._client_sock.recv(length)
```